# Python Multiprocessing Runaway Memory

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pathos

I have an expensive function to perform on many independent objects that is trivially parallel, so I'm trying to use the multiprocessing module. However, the memory consumption seems to be on a runaway up-and-to-the-right trajectory. See the attached image below.

Essentially I have a list of paths to large binary objects. I have a class that I instantiate with this list. In this class's `__iter__` method, I read the file from disk and yield it. The idea is that I iterate through this list of objects (which reads the file into memory) and perform some expensive operation. Below is some sample code to simulate this. I'm using `np.random.rand(100,100)` to simulate the reading of the large file into memory, and I'm only just indexing the [0,0] element if the matrix in the simulated expensive function.

```
import numpy as np
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
from memory_profiler import profile

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, my_list):
        self.name = 'foo'
        self.my_list = my_list

    def __iter__(self):
        for item in self.my_list:
            yield np.random.rand(100,100)

def expensive_function(foo):
    foo[0,0]

my_list = range(100000)
myclass = MyClass(my_list)

iter(myclass) # should not return anything

p = Pool(processes=4, maxtasksperchild=50)
p.map(expensive_function, iter(myclass), chunksize=100)
```

The issue can be seen in the plot. The memory consumption just seems to climb and climb. I would expect the total memory consumption to be ~4x the consumption of each individual child process, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

[image]

What's causing this runaway memory usage, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I think the simplest way to fix is just passing one single `np.random.rand(100, 100)` in. As all child process will have a copy, you don't need to also copy it in the main process.

Comment: Btw how to plot this plot? It looks good.

Comment: @Sraw the implication of doing that is that all of the processes are using the same random realization of 100x100 elements when the intention is probably to use different realizations. But then I think the solution is to just generate those elements in each child process instead of in the parent process, optionally using shared memory arrays (1 per child process) to minimize memory allocations

Comment: @Michael Yeah, you are brilliantly right :) If the array can be constructed from the child process, it would be the best.

Comment: I'm the `pathos` author.  Note that using `close`, `join`, and `clear` will close a pool, free up processes, and delete the pool object from the pool singleton dict.  This can help with memory management if you are calling the map function several times.

Comment: So I'm afraid that my example might have been overly contrived. In reality I'm not generating a random numpy matrix. I'm reading from a data file and then performing some expensive calculations. Generating a random matrix is just a stand-in to have something that's non-trivial enough for these benchmarks, but still reasonably quick.

Comment: Can you read from the data file from within the child process instead of from the parent process?

Comment: Did you try a similar memory profiling with a non-blocking map?

Answer (score 1):

Each time that a child begins to invoke `expensive_function`, it's receiving a new `np.random.rand(100,100)` array from `MyClass.__iter__`. These arrays are persisting in the main process, so of course the memory usage continues to grow; the child processes aren't able to clean these up, they exist in the parent process. Note how the peak is a little under 8 GiB, or about how much data you should expect to generate (100000 arrays with 100x100 entries, 8 bytes per entry)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a couple of thoughts. First, it's not clear that this is "about how much data you should expect." Why does each child receive a new array and persist it in memory? The array isn't assigned to any variables. Moreover, my understanding (which might be erroneous) of the `maxtasksperchild` argument is that it forces the pool to close a child and start a new one after X tasks. In this case, I would expect at most 50 x 4 arrays to be held in memory at once. But that gets back to the first question - why are these arrays persisted in memory in the first place?

Comment: The intention is to read an array into memory, operate on it, discard it, and then read the next one. It seems like a trivially parallel problem, and the default behavior of multiprocess seems ill-suited to that scenario.

Comment: The array is assigned to a variable implicitly, you just didn't name it yourself. What matters is that an 80 kiB object is created on each call to `MyClass.__iter__`, and then it gets copied to each child. The children are **not** persisting memory, the parent process is; your code is asking for 100k arrays, which numpy dutifully provides. This is simply an implementation issue, have a look at [multiprocessing's shared memory tools](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html); allocate some shared memory arrays, and then fill + yield them instead of making new ones